# Web2py : SQLForm labels option not overriding labels in view

Tags: forms, web2py

I have a simple SQLform, where I'm trying to override the labels so they are more meaningful to the user :

> form = SQLFORM(db.UserData, submit_button='Report now !', **labels** =
>   {'title':'Article Title', 'link':'Link to article',
>   'htmlcontent':'Content in HTML format', 'textcontent':'Content in text
>   format', 'source':'Your name', 'imageurl':'Image to the article',
>   'briefdescription':'Brief article excerpt', 'iscontentavailable':
>   'Ignore this'})

The labels for **htmlContent**, **imageurl**, **briefdescription** & **textcontent** are not being replaced.

Any idea what I should be checking or where I might be going wrong ?

Comment: can you post the model for db.UserData?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a easy name for your fields when defining your table, with labels:

```
db.define_table('system',
            Field('version', label='System Version', length=4),
            Field('db', label='System Database', length=10),
            Field('modules', label='Modules loaded', length=50)
            )
```

and Using placeholder HTML5 property with a custom form, you can put a tip into the textboxes:

```
{{=form.custom.begin}}
{{form.custom.widget.title['_placeholder']='Article Title'}}
{{form.custom.widget.link['_placeholder']='Link to article'}}
....
{{=form.custom.end}}
```

To add a label you can use jquery:

```
$('#title').val($('#title').val() + 'Article Title');
```